# Perl Compare Strings without Numbers

Tags: perl

I have 2 variables:

```
my $var1 = 'package-name-1.4';
my $var2 = 'package-name-1.5';
```

What I'm trying to do, is to compare $var1 to $var2, while excluding the numbers.

I have looked online and tried Regex but I can't get it working, I'd greatly appreciate some help.

What I have in mind is as follows:

```
if (removeNumbers($var1) =~ removeNumbers($var2))
```

So that the result would be like comparing: package-name- with package-name-, thus evaluating true.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the easiest approach is just to remove all digits altogether:

```
sub remove_numbers {
  my ($orig) = @_;
  $orig =~ s/\d+//g;
  return $orig;
}
```

But it's a bit naïve: for example, `some-package-1.4.1` and `some-package-1.4` would be not equal. It's better to remove dots as well, but only if they follow digits (serving as separators).

```
  $orig =~ s/\d+[.]?//g;
```

Even more, perhaps the first hyphen that precedes the number should go also (so 'package-name' and 'package-name-1' (and even 'package-name-1.0-some-fancy-line' and 'package-name-some-fancy-line') would be treated the same:

```
  $orig =~ s/-?\d+[.]?//g;
```

UPDATE: Yet there's more than one way to do it:

```
  $orig = substr $orig, 0, rindex $orig, '-';
```

It's applicable if all the strings have the same format (version numbers are always at the end of the string, always follow the last hyphen, which is always there):

Used as follows:

```
if (remove_numbers($var1) eq remove_numbers($var2))
```

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, had to add this remark regarding decimal points; only then saw your edit. ) Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn't realise =~ could be used other than as a comparison operator.

Comment: and thanks again for clearing up the dots, didn't even realise that would have caused problems, just waiting to accept your answer :)

Comment: @Cristian `=~` is not a comparison operator.

Comment: @Cristan, `=~` is used to specify the operand of `m//`, `s///` and `tr///`. It doesn't perform a comparison. In fact, it doesn't even result in any opcodes.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance it is probably best simply to extract all the "words" (here meaning alphabetic strings) and compare the strings containing just those

For instance

```
sub words_only {
  join ' ', shift =~ /\b[a-z]+\b/ig;
}
```

would turn both `package-name-1.4` and `package-name-1.5` into `package name`, so this script correctly prints `MATCH`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1 = 'package-name-1.4';
my $var2 = 'package-name-1.5';

print words_only($var1) eq words_only($var2) ? 'MATCH' : 'NO MATCH';

sub words_only {
  join ' ', shift =~ /\b[a-z]+\b/ig;
}
```

Comment: I really wish people would use `\p{alpha}` instead of `[a-z]`, but perhaps it’s ok in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If your variables contain the same formatting, then you can try removing the digits in the strings and compare the results.